# concatenate two dropdown values into another dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, concatenation

i'm looking for a way to concatenate two dropdown values into another dropdown using jquery and php, i want to do the same i did on with the textbox

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#drop2').change(function() { 
        var currentVal = $('textarea').val();
        var one = $('#drop1').val();
        var two = $('#drop2').val() + "\n";
         two.replace("\n","<br/>");
        $('textarea').html(currentVal + one + " em " +  two) ;

    });
});
</script>
```

HTML part

```
<form id="inserirtextarea" action="#" method="post"> 
  <p>
    <select name="drop1" id="drop1">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <select name="drop2"  id="drop2">
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
    </select>
    <textarea name="txta" id="txta" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input name="btinsert" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Any help is appreciated if anyone tried similar please point me on the right direction

Comment: there is no co-ordination with the jquery and the html.

Comment: i have done with text_field if you want then i can provide you for your referance

Comment: I think, you need get the options tag from both select tag and create new select tag with colleted option tags.

Comment: oh yeah sorry i did the wrong code for jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$('<select>').html($('#drop1').html()+$('#drop1').html()).appendTo('#inserirtextarea');
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/eZgUF/2/)

Comment: what i'm looking for is something that i could join both dropdowns values into another dropdown with both values inside it